# Is there a way to backup all a bucket with s3cmd

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I can upload, get, delete or list files in a bucket with `s3cmd`:

```sh
s3cmd ls s3://y/
s3cmd put x.png s3://y/z

# etc.
```

Is there a way to get a backup of all the bucket (i.e: `s3://y`)?

Comment: What do you mean by "get a backup of all the bucket"? Do you want to download all files inside a bucket (`s3cmd sync`) or something else? See: [Amazon S3 Tools: S3 Sync - How To Sync Files to Amazon S3](https://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--recursive` with `get` command. Example:

```
s3cmd get --recursive s3://y
```